# How to use groupby method to combine rows or columns by using their mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

For example:

```
        a  b  c
coffee  1  2  3
sprite  2  3  1
coffee  1  3  2
coke    2  4  5
sprite  2  3  1
coke    3  4  5
```

if I wanna to use `groupby` method to combine these rows (or columns) by using their mean, how can I do that?

```
        a  b  c
coffee  x  x  x
sprite  x  x  x
coke    x  x  x
```

x is the mean

Answer (score 0):

As you said, it's call `groupby`. Use `level=0` to group again the index:

```
df
Out[65]: 
        a  b  c
coffee  1  2  3
sprite  2  3  1
coffee  1  3  2
coke    2  4  5
sprite  2  3  1
coke    3  4  5

df.groupby(level=0).mean()
Out[66]: 
          a    b    c
coffee  1.0  2.5  2.5
coke    2.5  4.0  5.0
sprite  2.0  3.0  1.0
```

Comment: Ah it works!!! And one more question, if I have 100 kinds of drinks, I only want to keep these 3 kinds of drinks' row in this dataframe, how can I drop all the rows except these 3?

Comment: df.loc[['coffee', 'coke', 'sprite']]